# Calculating the margin of error on an estimated total number of class instances in population

Tags: classification, inference, error

I have a completely random sample of size 10 from a population of objects (population size 1000, if that helps) which can belong to either one of two classes, A or B. Based on a guess from superficial traits a process has assigned each object in the sample to a class and also assigned a confidence score to the guess (being defined as the probability that an object with these traits belongs to the class it has been assigned). This is the output from running that process over a sample of 10 objects.

`[{class: A, confidence: 0.95},{class: A, confidence: 0.9},{class: A, confidence: 0.85},{class: A, confidence: 0.75},{class: B, confidence: 0.95},{class: B, confidence: 0.95},{class: A, confidence: 0.96},{class: A, confidence: 0.5},{class: B, confidence: 0.8},{class: B, confidence: 0.75},]`

What calculations would I do to infer how many objects in the entire population belongs to class A, and how would I calculate the error of margin to a confidence of 90%?